# como imprimo o llevo a una variable un elemento del resultado de datatable por ejemplo solo quiero el dato de nombre_usuario

Tags: json, datatable

```
"columns": [ 
            { "data": "id" }, 
            { "data": "usuario" }, 
            { "data": "nombre_usuario" }, 
            { "data": "apellido_usuario" } 
           ]
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: ¿Estas usando JQuery Datatables?

Comment: SI EL MISMO JQUERY DATATABLE

Comment: si te refieres a la columna seleccionada puedes usar `var selData = table.rows(".selected").data().toArray();` y para seleccionar un unico campo `selData[0].nombre_usuario`, si quieres una respuesta mas detallada, te recomiendo que pulses [edit] y generes un [mcve]